# If correct, Bell's Theorem rules out local variables and suggests a superdeterministic for to the Universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality

If Bell's Theorem is correct and Quantum Mechanics cannot rely upon 'local variables'. Bell suggests that a probable solution is the existence of a Super-determined order upon the construct of our Universe. Bell stated the following during a radio interview in the 1980s:

> There is a way to escape the inference of superluminal speeds and spooky action at a distance. But it involves absolute determinism in the universe, the complete absence of free will. Suppose the world is super-deterministic, with not just inanimate nature running on behind-the-scenes clockwork, but with our behavior, including our belief that we are free to choose to do one experiment rather than another, absolutely predetermined, including the "decision" by the experimenter to carry out one set of measurements rather than another, the difficulty disappears. There is no need for a faster than light signal to tell particle A what measurement has been carried out on particle B, because the universe, including particle A, already "knows" what that measurement, and its outcome, will be."  (BBC Interview with Bell 1985)

Is there further evidence to confirm or reject a Super-determined Universal Construct, outside of John Bell's Theorem?

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. You're basically asking for a review of current progress in superdeterminism. I think you really need to be more specific what you are asking.

Comment: What is the Universal Construct?

Comment: It's *unclear what you're asking*. Bell's theorem implies there is no local *and* realist interpretation of quantum mechanics, but does not directly imply superdeterminism.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Bell's theorem might not be correct?  What step in the proof do you find unconvincing?

Comment: John: Sincere apologies for the lack of clarity. I have reworded the question as requested. Marcus

Comment: This may be of interest: http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3440

Comment: WillO:  I am suggesting that QM cannot and should not be permitted to continue with the assumption of local variables. If these are dispensed with, we might move forward with the more likely explanation that is offered by a Super-determined  Universe, regardless of its unpalatable nature and or the fear it might strike into the heart of Physicist and Philosopher alike. I would like to hear of any substantial evidence to contradict the Super-determinist  position.

Comment: sounds vaguely similar to bohms idea of the implicate vs explicate order. also a natural question is how "super determinism" is different from a "local hidden variable theory". my feeling is that early on the concept of "observation" got mixed up in QM interpretation wrt human vs apparatus. there is some research into so-called "superclassical" theories. further discussion here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon. also would suggest the _math_ concept of locality is not strictly matching the intuitive concept due to very tricky subtleties in formalism...

Comment: @vzn: How do you equate super determinism and local hidden variable theory? Super-determinism would hardly appear to be local to anything other than itself?

Comment: have not encountered bells idea of "superdeterminism" in his writing, it seems like a half-thought out idea, maybe someone can find/ cite something more specific/ academic. somehow superdeterminism as a concept has to account for the key idea of (non)locality. fyi wikipedia has more. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism have not heard of much research building on it. btw another new/ related area of study in this area is called "emergent QM" and has several years of conferences at this pt...

Comment: vzn Determinism is certainly not 'half thought out', it is one of the primary sources of Philosophical debate. I think the most interesting development in Physics this century is the reality that Philosophy and Physics are upon an very real and serious collision course.  The impact will certainly result in a Big Bang and possibly the next great Scientific Paradigm shift. If you have time, maybe you might read my paper on the question and let me know what you think?

Comment: I just think.you want to promote your paper... btw any source (verifiable) for bells quote?

Comment: @lalala, the OP gives a reference for the comments - a BBC interview with Bell. I also did a brief search that gives a similar referenced source for Bell's comments and quotes him verbatim: http://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/superdeterminism.html

Comment: @Steve well, the BBC attribution is not precise enough to locate it, isnt it.

Comment: @lalala, the link I've given quotes it as a radio 3 interview, and provides a book source. There's no reason to disbelieve these sources surely?

Comment: @lala Whats the reason for the harsh words 'trying to promote your paper'? I am using this forum like anyone else, and am trying to think about ideas that Bell's inequality points to. There is little to be gained by such an aggressive post.  There are multiple sources for Bells statement. You can find them on the net, even wiki under superdeterminism. |Do you actually have a scientific or philosophical view on the matter or do you have other reasons for posting?  Bell himself suggests that his theorem can be explained by Superdeterminism, hence the original question posted here.

Comment: Any post that begins "If Bell's theorem is correct..." is going to (justifiably) set off a lot of crackpot alarms.  If you're really suggesting that there might be an error in an exceptionally simple and well vetted argument, you'd better start by a) pointing to the *specific* "error" and b) acknowledging that it's 99.9999% sure you've failed to understand something.  When I encounter a post that starts "If it's really true that 2+2=4....", that's where I stop reading.  This is no different.

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat misreading his words there. `rules out local variables and suggests superdeterminism` -- instead, what he's saying is `it rules out local variables UNLESS there's superdeterminism`.

Superdeterminism is a potential way to keep local realism in tact, is what Bell is saying.

BUT it is in my opinion a completely untenable approach. The superdeterminism answer to the violation of Bell's Inequalities basically amounts to, "The entire universe works according to local realism, BUT the entire universe has conspired to make itself look like local realism is not the case". Though my opinion is probably not worth much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we do not need superdeterminism: QM is OK as it stands without it. Superdeterminism seems to be necessary if we do not believe in the standard formulation of QM and we want a hidden  variable theory which is local and realistic and can explain the phenomenology of QM.

Actually the Bell theorem, *together with the results of experiments accumulated along the years*,  imply that there is no local realistic  hidden-variable theory capable to explain the phenomenology of Quantum Mechanics. All that is true provided all *loopholes* in interpreting the above  experimental data which should confirm the violation of the CHSH inequality are fixed. One of these loopholes (I think the only one remaining)  regards superdeterminism, the last apparent (much more philosophical than physical) chance to keep both locality and realism in a hidden variable theory.

What is nowadays named "Bell theorem" is actually a statement of this type: "every local realistic hidden-variable  theory capable to explain the phenomenology of QM must satisfy the  CHSH inequality".

**Realistic** means that all observables are always defined (this is not the case for QM, as there exist incompatible observables). **Local** means that no superluminal transmission of physical information is permitted.

This reformulation of Bell's results is recent (this century) and I think it is due to Legget.

You cannot find that type of statement in the famous 1964 paper by Bell. There, a more elaborated philosopical position was proposed, relying on the original EPR analysis.

Furthermore the used inequality in that paper was not the CHSH one, but another version (the proper Bell inequality) much more difficult to experimentally test (however Clauser did it, I think in 1969).

I would like to finally stress that, actually, there is a realistic *non-local* hidden variable theory observationally  equivalent to the standard non-relativistic QM. That is the deBroglie-Bohm theory.

Answer (score 0):

Bell's theorem is the statement of an inequality derived from a pair of simple assumptions. So, any statement that implies that the theorem is wrong, would imply that he (and everybody else who checked it) made a mistake in the derivation. So, I'd say it is reasonable to accept that the theorem is correct.

The irony is that Bell's theorem is *violated* by nature, as demonstrated by experiments that have recently been awarded the Nobel prize. What this mean is not that Bell's theorem is not correct, but that one or both of the assumptions must be wrong. This is where we are with our scientific understanding of quantum mechanics.

Many people are not happy with that, so they try to come up with ways to "interpret" it. But those interpretations are in general non-scientific because there are no ways to determine whether they are correct through experimental observations. I suspect (correct me if I'm wrong) that super-determinism is one of those non-scientific interpretations.